# Python 3.3 cannot find any pip installed package on OSX?

Tags: macos, virtualenv, pip, virtualenvwrapper, python-3.3

I recently installed the Python 3.3 DMG from Python.org.

I have pip, virtualenv, and virtualenv-wrapper installed.

When I do:

```
$ mkvirtualenv -p /usr/local/bin/python3 someenv
```

The environment gets created as expected.

When I then do a pip install, like say:

```
(someenv) $ pip install beautifulsoup4
```

It installs correctly (no errors).

When I then fire up python:

```
(someenv) $ python
Python 3.3.0 (v3.3.0:bd8afb90ebf2, Sep 29 2012, 01:25:11) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import bs4
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'bs4'
```

I've also tried a few other packages: pytz, pymemoize, mock, and all seem to suffer from the same "No module named ..." problem.

Looking in the virtual environment's site-packages directory, the packages are there, it's just that the interpreter cannot seem to find them.  If I do a `pip freeze` all installed packages are listed.

Any suggestions?

If it helps, I'm using:

- Python 3.3 (again, installed from the .dmg at Python.org)
- pip v1.2.1
- virtualenv-wrapper v1.8.2
- distribute 0.6.28
- OSX 10.7 (Lion)

Edit: as requested, the output of `sys.path` is:

```
['', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python33.zip', 
'/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3', 
'/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/plat-darwin', 
'/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/lib-dynload', 
'/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages']
```

And as such what is missing is: `/Users/aparkin/.envs/someenv/lib/python3.3/site-packages' -- the virtual environment's site-packages directory.

Edit 2: as well, doing an `ls -l` on the site-packages directory gives:

```
$ ls -l .envs/someenv/lib/python3.3/site-packages/
total 168
drwxr-xr-x  7 aparkin  staff    238 18 Oct 11:49 PyMemoize-0.1.1-py3.3.egg-info
drwxr-xr-x  3 aparkin  staff    102 18 Oct 11:51 __pycache__
drwxr-xr-x  7 aparkin  staff    238 18 Oct 11:34 beautifulsoup4-4.1.3-py3.3.egg-info
drwxr-xr-x  9 aparkin  staff    306 18 Oct 11:32 bs4
drwxr-xr-x  8 aparkin  staff    272 18 Oct 11:31 distribute-0.6.28-py3.3.egg
-rw-r--r--  1 aparkin  staff    237 18 Oct 11:31 easy-install.pth
drwxr-xr-x  6 aparkin  staff    204 18 Oct 11:49 memoize
drwxr-xr-x  7 aparkin  staff    238 18 Oct 11:51 mock-1.0.0-py3.3.egg-info
-rw-r--r--  1 aparkin  staff  75204 18 Oct 11:51 mock.py
drwxr-xr-x  4 aparkin  staff    136 18 Oct 11:31 pip-1.2.1-py3.3.egg
drwxr-xr-x  9 aparkin  staff    306 18 Oct 11:44 pytz
drwxr-xr-x  8 aparkin  staff    272 18 Oct 11:44 pytz-2012f-py3.3.egg-info
-rw-r--r--  1 aparkin  staff     30 18 Oct 11:31 setuptools.pth
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A new feature of Python 3.3 is a standard way to create and manage virtual environments, [pyvenv](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/venv.html#module-venv).  You should use it instead.

That said, you still should be able to make the old `virtualenv` work.  One thing to check is the value of `sys.path` when using the virtualenv `python` that fails.  You should see the virtualenv `site-packages` directory on it.  If so and imports still don't work, check the virtualenv lib directories including `site-packages` for the correct file permissions.

Update: The contents of virtualenv `site-packages` looks reasonable at first glance.  But the value of `sys.path` looks suspiciously like that of the standard `python3.3`, not one running from a `virtualenv`.  So check to make sure you really are using that one.  Try running the virtualenv python with an absolute path, like:

```
/path/to/someenv/bin/python3.3 -c 'import sys;print(sys.executable);print(sys.path)'
```

Also make sure you have no Python-related environment variables set, like `PYTHONPATH` or shell aliases or functions for `python`.

```
env | grep PYTHON
echo $PATH
which python
type python
```

Comment: I knew about pyvenv, but assumed that the virtual environment utilities I've previously used would still work with Python 3.3  Is this not the case (ie are you *required* to use pyvenv with Python 3.3 for virtual environments)?  Looking at `sys.path` I don't see the virtual environments `site-packages` directory, any reason why that would be, or how to fix it (short of doing `sys.path.append(...)` in any script I write)?

Comment: Something is wrong then. I just tried installing `distribute`, `pip`, and `virtualenv` with the same python.org python3.3 and `pip` seems to install packages as expected.  I did not try `mkvirtualenv` though.  You could update your question to include the value of `sys.path` you see and the results of `ls -l <someenv>/lib/python3.3/site-packages/`.

Comment: Ok, sorry for the late commenting on this, I've been sick & away from work (& thus this computer).  Following-up: absolute path to `python3` shows the correct `sys.path`. absolute path to `python` (no 3), shows the *incorrect* `sys.path`. If I just do `python3` imports work correctly, but `python` gets an incorrect `sys.path` & thus imports do not work (as mentioned in the question). So a simple workaround is to just always do `python3`, but I wonder why this happened. The `env` command displays no output, the 1st item in `$PATH` is the path to the virtual environment.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because you set an `alias` for python in your terminal.

If you use zsh, just use an editor (e.g vim) to open `~/.zshrc`, and delete the alias for python, and then run `source ~/.zshrc` in your terminal or close the terminal windows and reopen it.

If you don't use zsh, the principle is the same, just delete the alias.

This will solve your problem.